# I am stuck with this code, kindly guide me - get & set methods in Java?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am stuck in this below code, especially the below part

```
public String getBalanceForCid(double balance){
        double b = 0;
        if (cid = custid)
            b = balance;
        else
            b;
        return
            b;
}
```

Please guide me the right way.

### Here is full code fyr

```
package practices;

public class Bank {

    public Bank(){
        cid = 0;
        cname = "";
        actno = 0;
        balance = 0;
    }

    public Bank(int custid, String custname, int custno, double custbal){
         cid = custid;
         cname = custname;
         actno = custno;
         balance = custbal;
    }


    public void setCustid(int custid){
         cid = custid;
    }

    public void setCustname(String custname){
         cname = custname;
    }

    public void setCustno(int custno){
        actno = custno;
    }

    public void setCustbal(double custbal){
        balance = custbal;
    }

    public int getCustoid(){
        return cid;
    }

    public String getCustname(){
        return cname;
    }

    public int getCustno(){
        return actno;
    }

    public double getCustbal(){
        return balance;
    }

    public String getBalanceForCid(double balance){
        double b = 0;
        if (cid = custid)
            b = balance;
        else
            b;
        return
            b;
    }


        private int cid;
        private String cname;
        private int actno;
        private double balance;
    }
```

above is my challenge (I am typing this message here again because I am getting message from SOF to add more details

Comment: What is the requirement? What doesn't work? Why? What was the expected behaviour? What happened instead? If you just dump code without explaining, how can we help?

Comment: And the question is??

Comment: you do need an else block remove it and you need `==` in if not just `=` or you could remove the entire code in `getBlanceForCid()` just add this `return cid == custid ? balance.toString() :"0";`

Comment: a function signature like `String getBalanceForCid(double balance)` is quite probably total nonsense, for several reasons

Comment: Are you sure that a Bank contain only one account ?

Comment: `I am stuck in this below code` what stuck refer to. Kindly be specific what you need. is there any error thrown or logical mistake ? Also you are not returning correct datatype.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but I don't think this method should be inside the `Bank` class. I think you should have an array of `Bank` objects and you should go through it to find the `Bank` instance with a particular `cid` and get its `balance`.

Comment: Hi friends, here i am learning this method and stuck in this problem.  I changed String getbalance....(double.....) to double getBalance and one error is resolved.  However there is one more error after else statement.  Expectation is if I put an account number, it should throw the bank balance

Comment: @JanakiShantharam what is custId? You are trying to reference custId which is not in class level scope.

Comment: @RamPrakash it is Customer ID

Comment: @JanakiShantharam terminology: functions **throw** exceptions (when there's something wrong) but they **return** values. May I really really suggest to spend some more time on the OO theory before you start writing code? My feeling that a great deal of your problems stem from the fact that your object is improperly designed because you're struggling with the very concept of objects.

Comment: @JanakiShantharam what is your requirement for getBalanceForCid method?

Comment: @JanakiShantharam i think you are passing customer id to `getBalanceForCid()`. If i am right then you should change `double balance` to `int custid`

Comment: @jackjay you might be right!!

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus to getBalanceForCid(...) method:

1. you should read in manual about `if/else` conditions
2. you should read in manual about types/returning data types from methods and generally about methods. Then about accessors and mutators in classes.